# Trying to scale a port in Circuitikz. Getting rotation instead

Tags: circuitikz

I’m drawing a simple circuit for a homework assignment meant to go out tomorrow.  Here’s the code:

```
\begin{circuitikz}
%  \draw[help lines] (-3,-3) grid (5,5);
  \node[nand port] (nand0) at (0,0) {};
  \node[or   port] (or0)   at (0,3) {};
  \node[ieeestd buffer port, scale=.8] (tri0) at (3,3) {};

  \draw (or0.in 2) -- ++(-.5,0)
                   to[inline not, *-] ($(nand0.in 1) + (-.5,0)$)
                   -- (nand0.in 1);
  
  \draw (or0.in 1)   -- ++(-1.5,0) node[left] {$a$};
  \draw (or0.in 2)   -- ++(-1.5,0) node[left] {$b$};
  \draw (nand0.in 2) -- ++(-1.5,0) node[left] {$c$};

  \draw (tri0.in 1) -- (or0.out);
  \draw (tri0.out) -- ++(1,0) node[right] {$F$};
  \draw (tri0.down) |- (nand0.out);
  
\end{circuitikz}
```

And, here’s the result:
[image]

Great!  But, wait.  That NOT gate looks a bit big.  Let’s scale it down.  I only make one change, to the line with the inline not.

`to[inline not, *-, scale=.8]`

Now, I get this result:

[image: Bad Rotation]

I’m guessing that somewhere in the finely crafted manual, which I have read before, there is talk about rotations of inline elements.  But, I can’t find it at the moment.

Can anyone help out?  Why does the NOT gate get skewed and the “dot” misplaced, when all I did was scale it?  Should I be scaling it some other way?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can't use `scale` in a path component. You must use the class scale, like `logic ports/scale`. Check the manual (I'll add a proper answer as soon as I reach a computer l

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size of the ports is more or less the IEEE standard, but I can understand that the simple ones look a bit too big.

The problem is that you can't use `scale` in a `to` command (not in `circuitikz` nor in `Ti*k*Z`, really). Page 35 of the manual, under the section *Component size*:

[image]

You can use the class options:

`to[inline not, *-, logic ports/scale=0.8]`

to obtain what you are looking for. I suggest, though, creating your styles and using them:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{logic ports=ieee}
\tikzset{small buffer/.style={%
        ieeestd buffer port, /tikz/circuitikz/logic ports/scale=.8},
    small inline not/.style={%
        inline not, /tikz/circuitikz/logic ports/scale=0.8}
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \node[nand port] (nand0) at (0,0) {};
    \node[or   port] (or0)   at (0,3) {};
    \node[small buffer] (tri0) at (3,3) {};

  \draw (or0.in 2) -- ++(-.5,0)
                   to[small inline not] ($(nand0.in 1) + (-.5,0)$)
                   -- (nand0.in 1);

  \draw (or0.in 1)   -- ++(-1.5,0) node[left] {$a$};
  \draw (or0.in 2)   -- ++(-1.5,0) node[left] {$b$};
  \draw (nand0.in 2) -- ++(-1.5,0) node[left] {$c$};

  \draw (tri0.in 1) -- (or0.out);
  \draw (tri0.out) -- ++(1,0) node[right] {$F$};
  \draw (tri0.down) |- (nand0.out);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: next time, please post a complete, compilable LaTeX code, not just a snippet...

Comment: I'm agree with you: PS: next time, please post a complete, compilable LaTeX code, not just a snippet... +1

Comment: Ah!  I knew it was in the manual somewhere.  For the record, I was not being sarcastic.  I actually think the manual is very readable -- it is finely crafted.